# Doctrine proxy serialization issue with Zend

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-auth

I have a problem with zf2 authentication. The problem occurs when zend try to serialize Doctrine entity which has attribute defined as Doctrine Proxy.
I got 
**PHP Warning:  unserialize(): Function spl_autoload_call() hasn't defined the class it was called**

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Did you read this? http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/architecture.html#serializing-entities

Comment: Thanks for comment, I didn't read that before, but all I'm using is standard Zend\Authentication and 'doctrine.authenticationservice.orm_default'. There my Entity will be serialized. I didn't consider it as my concern.

Answer (score 0):

For doctrine entity/document serialisation purpose i use this module https://github.com/Spea/JMSSerializerModule. Hope it will help

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but as I wrote in comment above: all I'm using is standard Zend\Authentication and 'doctrine.authenticationservice.orm_default'. There my Entity will be serialized. I didn't consider it as my concern. I will keep looking.